# d3.js styled area pie chart - trying to avoid old/boring pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**Hi All,**
I saw this great work by [Tristan Guillevin](https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/guillevin/viz/LandOfColors/Landofcolors) and if anyone could help with ideas on how to achieve something similar using d3.js that would be great.

In mathematics there is this thing called the [Moser's circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dividing_a_circle_into_areas) but we don't need something that elegant and precise here - I'm just trying to brute force something nice that don't look like that old pie chart where all lines go to the center passing a simple data like:

`var data = {a: 9, b: 20, c:30, d:8, e:12}`

[image: Tristan Guillevin]

Comment: I think I found it - this graph is actually the [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) and d3.js supports the voronoi() function.